# Can you explain what "for which" means here in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrases, relative-clauses, mathematics

I'm learning "Composition of Functions" in Aleks and come across this sentence. But I can't understand what "for which" means in that sentence:"The domain of f.g is the set of all x in the domain of g for which g(x) is in the domain of f."

I found a similar answer here ["Such that" versus "for which"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/294688/such-that-versus-for-which)

but I'm confused because I don't know which antecedents the word "which" in "for which" refer to: "the domain of f.g", "the set of all x" or "the domain of g" ???

Can you explain it to me? I'd appreciate it.
[image]

Comment: "*p* for which *q*" means "*p* that cause *q* to be true"

Comment: It’s the same as “for whom” except for things instead of people.

Comment: So if x is in the domain of g, and g(x) is in the domain of f, then (and only then) x is in the domain of f.g.

Comment: In your example, the antecedent of "which" is *x*.

Comment: That Question isn't about English. It's about maths or logic or some such but not English.

Part of the problem is that you equate *Such that* and *for which*, when in fact they're nt the same at all.

Answer (score 1):

> - *The domain of `f·g` is the set of all `x` in the domain of `g`
>
>     **for which** `g(x)` is in the domain of `f`.*

This is mathematical English, not colloquial English. In colloquial English *for which* and *such that* cannot be freely interchanged; but in mathematical phrasing like this, they can. This sentence means the same thing:

> - *The domain of `f·g` is the set of all `x` in the domain of `g`
>
>     **such that** `g(x)` is in the domain of `f`.*

*For which* introduces a restrictive relative clause bound by the quantifier *all*; it restricts the set to only certain `x`'s, and the property those `x`'s share is stated the set phrase *for which* (or *such that*).

These set phrases are used when a simple relative clause won't do the job. If the sentence was

> - *The domain of `P` is the set of all `x` in `Q`
>
>     **which** are zeroes of the Zeta function.*

there's no need to pied-pipe a preposition *for*, and there's no problem.

But in the example provided, *all `x`* isn't the subject of the restrictive relative,
so you can't use *which* as the subject, but rather posit some oblique relation,
and that calls for a preposition, which gets stranded when *which* is moved to the front

> - **The domain of `f·g` is the set of all `x` in the domain of `g`
>
>     **which** `g(x)` is in the domain of `f` **for**.*

which is so clumsy that it's promptly pied-piped and glued together with *which* into a fixed phrase.